# jquery code is not working in IE11 when a control is having runat=server

Tags: jquery

i am creating an asp.net application which uses jquery as well. my application is working perfectly in chrome but not in IE.

```
 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="" />
        <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/favicon.ico" />
        <title>Login | Palle University</title>
        <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="assets/css/ionicons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var emailRegex = /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
            var isFormDataValid = true;
            function validateLogin()
            {
                a=validateEmail($('<%=tbEmail.ClientID%>'));
                b=validatePassword($(tbPwd));
                if (a && b)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
```

and calling validateLogin() function from a button click.

The part of html code is as follows.

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="lblEmail">Email address</label>
                                    <input type="email" runat="server" class="form-control" id="tbEmail" placeholder="Enter email">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="lblPwd">Password</label>
                                    <input type="password" runat="server" class="form-control" id="tbPwd" placeholder="Password">
                                </div>

                                  <label style="display: block;padding-left: 15px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="checkid" type="checkbox"/>Remember Me</label>

                                <asp:Button runat="server" OnClick="btnSignIn_Click" OnClientClick="return validateLogin()" Text="SIGN IN" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-block"></asp:Button>
                                Forgot Password?<a href="#ReceivePassword" data-toggle="pill">click here</a><br />
                                To change your Password?<a href="#ChangePassword" data-toggle="pill">click here</a>
                                <div id="errmsg2" class="btn-danger" runat="server">

                            </div>
```

when i execute the code in IE it is showing a message stating tbEmail is undefined. Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: when i use <%=tbEmail.ClientID%> in validateLogin function it is working fine. But the control id is not modified while rendering since i am not using either master page or the control is not defined in user control.

Comment: try adding your site in trusted in IE 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use ID in the jQuery selector, it should be pre-fixed with '#'. Try changing the line to read like this:

```
a=validateEmail($('#<%=tbEmail.ClientID%>'));
```

This should get it working.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i will try this later. Now my priority is to make my application work in Chrome and MFF.